# Google Maps Licensing and SocialEngine/Joomla/Drupal plugins

Tags: google-maps, plugins, licensing, api-key, socialengine

The following plugin for SocialEngine uses Google Maps for proximity searches, maps, etc.

http://www.socialengine.net/customize/mod-page?mod_id=211&mod=Google-Map--Locations-Plugin

Additional Note: The website will also be using a directory plugin.

Is it necessary to purchase a commercial Google Maps API key for this kind of activity? Somebody suggested that a Google Maps API key was going to cost a lot of money, and for a starter business this wouldn't be possible.

Plugins do not tend to mention this, but I am led to believe that there may be an issue here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the information you need in the [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) and via the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html). Specifically, search the FAQ page for the Q&A "Can I use the Google Maps API on a commercial website?"

Essentially, as long as your site isn't getting super high traffic, you should be fine with the free level of service.

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps API is free for all non-commercial and commercial use, and you can use it in your commercial site:

1. if you keep the default Google branding
2. and if the map will be public to anyone

You need to buy a special key if you are planning to use the map in private or sell map products that will be for private use only.

Answer (score 0):

There is news on the way Google executes its license ... We just have been contacted by Google and were told that selling a Maps API Implementation to a customer requires a OEM License. This is regardless wether you charge a one time fee or a recurrent fee. This is regardless if you operate the Maps API Implementation on your own server or on the customers server. This was new to me and I did not read that from the license texts.

So, if I interpret this correctly and if you are planning to subcontract a plugin for your website from another company (aka a Maps API Implementation), the other company should have a Google Maps OEM License and will charge you for API Traffic using that plugin. This seems not to apply if you are using a public-domain plugin or a plugin developed in house.